# How to clear the Cargo cache?

Tags: rust, rust-crates, rust-cargo

When I run `cargo build`, various libs get stored within the folder `/usr/local/lib/rustlib/`.

What is the correct way to clear these libs? I could `rm` these files manually, but would that be the right thing to do? I noticed that `/usr/local/lib/rustlib/manifest` is a file containing a list of the fill file paths of all the libs, and hence might be breaking something if I remove these files manually.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe that `manifest` file is just for the built-in libraries, i.e. those distributed with `rustc`. `cargo` itself stores things in `~/.cargo` ([for the moment](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/148)), if you do wish to just remove all the libraries then deleting that directory won't break anything.

If you're just wanting `cargo` to rebuild/update dependencies you can run `cargo update`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `~/.cargo`, that is what I was looking for!

Comment: keep the `bin` folder if you don't want to reinstall all that cool Rust tools you've installed )

Comment: In particular, by default this will remove the `cargo` executable itself too.

Answer (score 65):

Install and run [cargo-cache](https://github.com/matthiaskrgr/cargo-cache) to clear the cache in the `~/.cargo` folder:

```bash
cargo install cargo-cache
cargo cache -a
```

Comment: error caused by "feature `resolver` is required" :sad_face:

Comment: error: no such subcommand: `cache`

Comment: @chovy did you remember to install cargo-cache first?

Comment: If you no longer have any need of any of the cargo crates, such as just wanting to compile a project and then freeing up the space afterward, the command to use is `cargo-cache --remove-dir all` (or `cargo-cache -r all` for short).

Comment: I found this useful when using dependencies with versions that cargo does not support. For example, Cargo will not download the correct dependency when you switch a dependency from `1.2.0-dev.1` to `1.2.0-dev.2`. It doesn't respect semver "pre-release versions" (Cargo doesn't document this) semver "build metadata" (documented).

Comment: I ran into an issue with the cache that made me unable to install/build `cargo-cache` normally. What worked for me was to just update rust (`rustup update`) so it wouldn't use cached builds made with previous versions of rustc. This was only possible since I did not need to use a specific version of rustc, but it did help give me the peace of mind that I was not going to break something by manually deleting files. Afterwards, I was able to install `cargo-cache` and have it do a full cache reset.