# importing 'HttpServer' from actix-web crate returns "no 'HttpServer' in root" error after importing serde_json crate in rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, serde, actix-web

I was using `actix-web` to make my project, but after importing the `serde_json` crate my code refused to compile and gave this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `actix_web::HttpServer`
 --> src/main.rs:1:41
  |
1 | use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
  |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^ no `HttpServer` in the root

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
```

which is weird, because before that it was working fine, so i decided to test it again on a different project using `cargo new`, with the following code presented in actix-web's documentation as an example:

```
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().route("/", web::get().to(HttpResponse::Ok)))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

and it continued to give the same error.

I tried using `cargo clean` to no avail, but when i degraded `actix-web = "4"` to `actix-web = "3"`, in my `Cargo.toml` file it started working again. I'm guessing this is a more general Rust problem.

`Cargo.toml` :

```
[package]
name = "project-name"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-files = "0.6.2"
actix-web = "4"
serde_json = "1.0.94"
```

I'm running rustc/cargo 1.68.0 and Arch Linux-6.1.1 x86-64 if that has something to do with it.

I've asked other people to try and reproduce it but in their machine it worked.

Comment: Hello, welcome, and thanks for putting effort into what is a very well structured question :) Do I understand correctly that the code above should already produce the error, or do I need to also `use` serde_json in some way to cause it?

Comment: I'm assuming that, if you try building your project within the [rust docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust), it will work. Maybe something strange is going on in your Cargo cache, so you [could try clearing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68854692/124257).

Comment: @fresskoma Haha, clearing the cache did work, in conjunction with cargo clean, thank you so much, after a bit of frustration it worked out. :)